# How can I pass a null value for date in vb.net to sql stored procedure?

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, parameters, null

My application is asp.net with vb.

In my page I have a textbox for passing date. If I didn't enter date and on clicking submit, I have to pass null value to the stored procedure.

I tried following codes such as `DBNull.Value` and `DateTime.MinValue`. In that case instead of null, `"#12:00:00#"` is passing. I have to pass Null.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just assign the parameter the value DBNull.Value

[EDIT]

If you are using SqlParameter  (thanks Jon) then you can set it like this if it gives any error

```
parameter.Value = DBNull.Value
```

Comment: it gives a conversion problem.can it be solved by Convert.ToDateTime(DBNull.Value)

Comment: DBNull.Value cannot be used as it generates an error "Object cannot be cast from DBNull.Value to other types"

Comment: The code given should be fine, if "parameter" is a SqlParameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim pflt_dateto As SqlParameter = cmd.CreateParameter
        pflt_dateto.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        pflt_dateto.DbType = SqlDbType.Int
        pflt_dateto.IsNullable = True
        pflt_dateto.ParameterName = "flt_dateto"

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(dateto) Then
            pflt_dateto.SqlValue = DBNull
        Else
            pflt_dateto.SqlValue = dateto
        End If

        cmd.Parameters.Add(pflt_dateto)
```

Since you set up the parameter nullable, the error will disappear. Now the issue is that .NET pass null integer as 0 so we need to deal with that.

Chao

Comment: Shouldn't this line be `pflt_dateto.SqlValue = DBNull.Value` ? I got the error: "DBNull is a type and cannot be used as an expression" without `.Value`